# spring boot adding Manifest entry key respresenting build version in maven pom.xml

Tags: maven-3, spring-boot

What I would like to do is be able to put the version of my build into the maven command line and have that build version arrive in the MANIFEST.MF file. I was hoping to use the spring-boot-maven-plugin to do so.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <!--put something here from the command line? -->
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I'm sorry that I haven't got a broken example for you to troubleshoot, but I can't seem to find any documentation on this the plugin usage examples that I have found don't cover anything like this.

Comment: You can do that with the normal mavan jar or war plugin. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/manifest-customization.html

Comment: Is there a reason you need the information specifically in MANIFEST.MF? If not, have you seen how Spring Boot handles custom application info?

Comment: M. Denium - that's true, but I am using spring boot, so unless I bypass its normal artifact creation process with my own (large risk of heaps of other things not working), then I have to follow their systems. geoand - MANIFEST.MF is the obvious most visible file to hold the build version in. I'm also not sure what you mean by Spring Boot handling custom application info. Searching their doco on that was not productive, can you be more specific?

Comment: I think the feature @geoand refers to is this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-application-info. And Marten is correct that you can use the normal jar plugin to create your manifest (the boot plugin only enhances what is already there).

Comment: The links @DaveSyer gives is exactly what I had in mind